# Kaiser window but desired frequency response extends beyond pi?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, window-functions

Passband : 0 to 0.5π
Stopband : 0.7π to 2π

Is there a way to reduce this to a 0 to π scale?

If I had to guess, we should be able to simply divide the edge frequencies by 2 and use the time scaling property of z-Transform. Can anyone confirm if this is a valid technique?

I am not sure if this is even a valid question but it was on my university's final last year.

Comment: My first guess would be that that's a typo, i.e., that the stopband is meant to be $[0.7,1]\pi$. In theory, the stopband could extend to $2\pi$, but in that case the filter would be complex-valued. I don't think that this is what they meant, because for a complex-valued filter they should have introduced another transition band to avoid the sharp transition from the stopband edge $2\pi$ to the passband edge at $\omega=0$.

Comment: I thought so. Wouldn't even be the first typo in the question.